# Magento Version 1.6.2.0 - Configurable Products be Master for Minimum Order Quantity

Tags: configurable-product

I am facing a problem. Maybe one of you has an idea how to solve the same.

a) I have created several configurable products consisting of simple products associated.

b) The stock amount goes by the associated simple products as our logistics software has to work with the same.

c) Now I am using the configurable product as kind of a bundle offer and clients should only be able to purchase minimum 25 items of this configurable product. Price is given a forced by the Configurable product settings already. But I would also like to force a minimum order quantity to this specific product.

d) It is no option to set the MOQ per simple individual products, as there is a MOQ already given (5 items, we are wholesaler)

In short: I want to force Magento to use the minimum quantity defined in the configurable product when buying Options from the same.

Excuse my english. It is not my native language. Hope I could be kind of clear, for what I am looking for.

Best regards

Ben

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest working wih Bundle products instead of configurable products, then what you can do is he following:

- Write a code that will show each simple products qty
- Write a further code that adds up all of the simple products qty
- Use this total, and resrict your add to cart button to 25

This is possible as I have heavy extensions on my Magento sites that use this, which includes breaking down the stock to ratio based on amount of items vs qty.

[image]

Hoever I can only give you the basics of what you would need to do to fulfill your idea.

I hope everything works out,

Comment: Hi @Digitalyst, thank you for your answer and your advise. Problem is, I am working with a configurable product Matrix and clients can chose from various colors for one simple product with the configurable product. Same might be true for your shop as well but for us we sell fabrics and product variation is a completely different product here. The Matrix is working pretty well and I would like to keep the same. Only problem as mentioned is that the restriction cannot be given. I know it is a kind of work around. If anybody has another idea I am happy to hear your comments.

Comment: Try this: http://bsscommerce.com/magento-minimum-quantity-of-configurable-product.html.